# Thread management/Working of spring @Async

Tags: java, spring, parallel-processing, thread-safety, spring-async

I am using `@Async` in my code to have 3 parallel calls from Rest controller to 3 different methods.

As per my servlet understanding(which might be wrong), when a request is received by spring `@RestController` method, a thread is created for it and henceforth for each new request a new thread would be created.

Request Thread 1 - 3 Async threads created
Request Thread 2 - 3 Async threads created

Now how does spring/Request threads knows which 3 Async thread belong to which thread i.e. Request Thread 1 or Request Thread 2.

There might be some sort of mapping which tells them.
I tried searching about `@Async` online but very little documentation is available on its working. Google is flooded with how to use code but not functioning.

Bottomline - Can someone explain me the working/thread management of `@Async` code

---

Updating with image for better explanation:

[image]

1) Request 1 comes in and spawn 3 threads(A1, A2, & A3) as it an Async call with respone R1, R2 & R3.
2) Request 2 comes in & does the same thing i.e. Request: A4, A5 & A6 with response as R1, R2 & R3..
3) Now my question is how does R1 , R2 & R3 realize that they are part of the same request i.e. Request 1. If it would have been a sequential call then the same thread would have propagated  from start to end. But after creation of 6 Async request, I can see only 6 thread in thread dump and no thread as Request 1 or Request 2. 
So how does on completion of R1, R2 & R3 the request 1 get complete **but not on completion of R1, R2 & R6** Who & where is the record kept that Request 1 is completed from R1 , R2 & R3.

Comment: `@ASync` in short doesn't do anything, it is an annotation. Without `@EnableAsync` it doesn't do anything either. Also what and how it does its  work depends on your `TaskExecutor`. Also your understanding of the `@RestController` is wrong, no threads are created, actually default servlet behavior is blocking and use threads from a thread pool (depending on your servlet container). It is async so as soon as the methods have dispatched your controller will return (unless you are returning a `Future` and call `get` which makes it a blocking call again defeating the purpose of `@Async` kind of).

Comment: The task executor is merely a way how thread would be like i.e. reused from pool or created & destroy for each request. When I say new thread for each request what I mean is each request is processed in a different thread doesn't matter if its created or picked from thread-pool. Also I am not concerned about the blocking nature, I think .isDone flags does it bit here. My question is how 2 different request which create 3 Async threads(i.e 6 in total) back track to their original caller thread

Comment: As stated generally they don't unless you are using `Future` or `CompletableFuture` and use `get` which will make it basically a sync call again (the request handling thread will block until the processes finish) if you don't use such a mechanism they simply don't wait and return immediately.

Comment: Call from controller:

Future<String> fut1 = class1.call1();
Future<String> fut2 = class2.call2();

while(! (fut1.isDone() && fut2.isDone()) )   {}

fut1.get();
fut2.get();

Now call1() & call2() are called for 2 different threads due to 2 different requests

call1() call completes for request 2 first but call2() completes for thread 1 first, but each would wait for their respective other Async sibbling call to complete

How does each Async call knows that to which parent request they belong because in thread pool only Async thread are visible once call is fired

Comment: That is what you are doing with `Future.get()` and is the whole point of the `Future` and basically has nothing to do with `@Async` as the `Future` is a default component from the JRE.

Answer (score 1):

For example, let's take the `findUser` method from [Spring's tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/)

```
@Async
public CompletableFuture<User> findUser(String user) throws InterruptedException {
    logger.info("Looking up " + user);
    String url = String.format("https://api.github.com/users/%s", user);
    User results = restTemplate.getForObject(url, User.class);
    // Artificial delay of 1s for demonstration purposes
    Thread.sleep(1000L);
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(results);
}
```

Assuming you are using `@EnableAsync`, each call to `findUser` actually calls a proxy that:

1. Creates a `CompletableFuture` instance.
2. Executes `findUser` in a different thread, passing the same `CompletableFuture` instance.

   - Once the execution finish, it updates the shared `CompletableFuture` instance.
3. Returns the `CompletableFuture` to the caller.

The ThreadPool is created at the beginning of your program, from which the proxy takes threads to run your code.

---

[The implementation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-aop/src/main/java/org/springframework/aop/interceptor/AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java) is in `AsyncExecutionInterceptor` class,  `invoke` method.